# Проблема с запуском телеграмм бота на Python!

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Написал Эхо-бота для тг бота для теста,

> python: can't open file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory

Сверху то, что выводит cmd, запущенная от имени администратора при вводе команды `python bot.py`
Файл с ботом также называется bot.py, в этом ошибки нет, пробовал ввести по другому в консоль:

```
python C:\Users\User\Desktop\Программитрование\python bot.py
```

Да, в названии папки ошибка, но так и задумано было при её создании(нет, заметил когда писал вопрос)

Как всё же запустить бота? Снизу приложу ещё код самого бота, в нём вроде всё ок, но всё же:

```py
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot('%5160080827:AAG3FevlFnuZ1DIfv1L46nX0NBecG1XzMak');

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def eho(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Просто для удобства рекомендую использовать pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

В консоли перейди в директорию с файлом с помощ'ю таких команд

```
cd \
cd Users\User\Desktop\Программитрование\python
```

Или же вам нужно сразу правильно указать директорию к файлу

```
python C:\Users\User\Desktop\Программитрование\python\bot.py
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но теперь возникла новая ошибка, теперь cmd выдаёт это: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Программитрование\python>python bot.py
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Программитрование\python\bot.py", line 11
    bot.polling(none_stop = True)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Попробуйте изменить название папки програмирование на английский

Comment: и я думаю что в `bot.polling` параметр `none_stop` лишний

Comment: Возможно вам нужно убрать  пробел  между параметром `None_stop` и =

Comment: Изменил на английский - не помогло, но оставил; убрал none_stop - не помогло, вернул к исходному; Убрал пробелы - не помогло, Всё также ругается на слово bot в 11 строке, чекнул другой гайд ещё, заметил, что не дописал interval = 0, сейчас код выглядит так: `import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot('%5160080827:AAG3FevlFnuZ1DIfv1L46nX0NBecG1XzMak');
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def eho(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

bot.polling(none_stop=True interval=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Запуск бота:

```
python C:\Users\User\Desktop\Программитрование\python\bot.py
```

Код эхо бота:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ваш токен");

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def eho(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]